# invokeAll() vs Guava ListenableFuture+addCallback()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, guava

I am wondering what will be the advantage of using `ListenableFuture+addCallback()` instead of `invokeAll()`, in case when I am only interested in getting result of all tasks at once.

Does `invokeAll()` hides any exception thrown? And do I need to take care of anything else if I am using `invokeAll()`, as `addCallback()` provides `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()` methods but no such functionality with `invokeAll()`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who forces you to use the `ListenableFuture`?

Comment: No on is forcing me, my question is out of interest and to know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `ListenableFuture`, you can submit any number of tasks and then pass the `ListenableFuture`s from those tasks to [`Futures.allAsList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList%28com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...%29), getting another `ListenableFuture` that will complete when *all* of the tasks have completed. There's also [`Futures.successfulAsList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList%28com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...%29), which succeeds even if some of the tasks fail and gives you a `null` result for each failed task.

You can then either block the current thread to wait for those results (using the normal `Future.get()`) or you can add a listener/callback to be called when they've completed if you don't want/need to block the current thread.

Example:

```
ListeningExecutorService executor = ...
List<Callable<Foo>> tasks = ...

List<ListenableFuture<Foo>> futures = Lists.newArrayList();
for (Callable<Foo> task : tasks) {
  futures.add(executor.submit(task));
}

final ListenableFuture<List<Foo>> resultsFuture
    = Futures.allAsList(futures);

// block until all tasks are done
List<Foo> results = resultsFuture.get();

// or add a callback to get called when the tasks complete
Futures.addCallback(resultsFuture, new FutureCallback<List<Foo>>() {
  @Override public void onSuccess(List<Foo> results) {
    // ...
  }

  @Override public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
    // ...
  }
}, someExecutor);
```

Comment: Can you please point me to some code? Of course I can google it, but when I tried before did not get any relevant code.

Comment: @Tingya: Added an example.

Comment: Thanks! This makes more sense now!

Comment: @ColinD I also have question on guava [ListenableFuture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336280/how-to-properly-deal-with-exceptions-coming-from-listenablefuture-guava). If possible can you review my design and help me clarify some of my doubts and how I should deal with them? I recently started working with Guava ListenableFuture and I like a lot but having some confusion regarding how to use them efficiently.

Comment: @ColinD hey are you around for quick chat. It will help me a lot to clear my understanding on how to use guava ListenableFuture properly. I am trying to implement sync and async implementation in my library so I am using future provided by Guava but need some suggestion on that. I will be in this [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74118/room-for-david-and-colind). If possible can you join whenever you are free.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutorService.invokeAll()` returns list of `Futures<?>` then you can iterate through this list and execute `future.get()` that will throw an exception if it occurs during computation or a result if no error occurs.

Here the example:

```
class SecondFailTask implements Callable<Integer> {
    private static volatile int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 2){
            throw new RuntimeException("Fail");
        } else {
            return counter;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        List<SecondFailTask> tasks = Arrays.asList(new SecondFailTask(),new SecondFailTask(),new SecondFailTask());
        List<Future<Integer>> futures =  e.invokeAll(tasks);
        for (Future<Integer> future : futures){
            try {
                System.out.println("Counter is " + future.get());
            }catch (ExecutionException ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getCause());
            }
        }
    }
```

Output is:

```
Counter is 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail
Counter is 3
```

I'm not sure that there is a way to grab the results of all tasks at once as far I understood `onSuccess()` or `onFailure()` executes after each task computation and in such way collecting results would be trick(with some global variable). I would prefer to use `ExecutorService.invokeAll()` but I'm not a guava expert and I might miss something.